# failure to set a LIST value in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to set a list value in my DynamoDB table like so:

```
{
  "TableName": "my-table",
  "Key": {
    "uid": {
      "S": "id-value"
    }
  },
  "UpdateExpression": " SET #actions = :actions",
  "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
    "#actions": "actions"
  },
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":actions": {
      "L": [
        "one",
        "two"
      ]
    }
  },
  "ReturnValues": "ALL_NEW"
}
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
{
  "message": "There were 8 validation errors:\n* InvalidParameterType: Expected params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':actions'].L[0] to be a structure\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '0' found in     params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':actions'].L[0]\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '1' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':actions'].L[0]\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '2' found in     params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':actions'].L[0]\n* InvalidParameterType: Expected params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':actions'].L[1] to be a structure\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '0' found in     params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':actions'].L[1]\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '1' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':actions'].L[1]\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key '2' found in     params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':actions'].L[1]",
  "code": "MultipleValidationErrors",
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Expected params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':actions'].L[0] to be a structure",
      "code": "InvalidParameterType",
      "time": "2018-12-19T15:21:49.307Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '0' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':actions'].L[0]",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2018-12-19T15:21:49.307Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '1' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':actions'].L[0]",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2018-12-19T15:21:49.307Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '2' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':actions'].L[0]",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2018-12-19T15:21:49.307Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Expected params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':actions'].L[1] to be a structure",
      "code": "InvalidParameterType",
      "time": "2018-12-19T15:21:49.307Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '0' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':actions'].L[1]",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2018-12-19T15:21:49.307Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '1' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':actions'].L[1]",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2018-12-19T15:21:49.307Z"
    },
    {
      "message": "Unexpected key '2' found in params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':actions'].L[1]",
      "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
      "time": "2018-12-19T15:21:49.307Z"
    }
  ],
  "time": "2018-12-19T15:21:49.308Z"
}
```

I know that a single entry can be added using list_append, but I need to set an entire list...
What am I doing wrong?

Is it possible to set an entire table in a single query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the the type of the values is missing.
Here is the correct structure:

```
{
  "TableName": "my-table",
  "Key": {
    "uid": {
      "S": "id-value"
    }
  },
  "UpdateExpression": " SET #actions = :actions",
  "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
    "#actions": "actions"
  },
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":actions": {
      "L": [
        {
          "S": "one"
        },
        {
          "S": "two"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "ReturnValues": "ALL_NEW"
}
```